# Why is @Model null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, null

View: Registration.cshtml

```
 @model MyNameSpace.Models.NewPatientRegistrationViewModel
 <div> ... All the HTML </div>
```

Model: AccountViewModels.cs

```
namespace MyNameSpace.Models
{

    public class RegistrationViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
        public string DOB { get; set; }
        public int DOBYear { get; set; }
        public int DOBMonth { get; set; }
        public int DOBDay { get; set; }

        public NewPatientRegistrationViewModel() { }
    }

}
```

Controller: AccountControllers.cs

```
    public ActionResult Registration()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

In the view, an reference to @Model comes up null, and throws a null exception error.  Still new to MVC... I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: You're not passing your viewmodel object to your View() call in your ActionResult.

Comment: Ok... help out a newbie.  Isn't that what return View(); does?  What am I missing?

Comment: return View() takes a model to be passed, so create a new RegistrationViewModel and pass that to your view

Comment: You need to pass your viewmodel object to the call to View(): `return View(yourViewModelObject);` of course actually having an object that you want to pass into the view for consumption/population.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change your Controller action to return the view model to the view

```
public ActionResult Registration()
{
    var model = new RegistrationViewModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

You can instantiate other properties on your view model before passing it back should you need that for your view to render

Comment: Thank you!  I'll mark as answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why model could be null,

A. You could be passing null from the get method. The approved answer points this.

B. You may have a field which has the same name as the parameter you're binding your model on post.

```
public ActionResult Add(ContentImage image)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        UploadImage(Request.Files["Image"]);

        //Some other actions
    }

    return View("Edit", image);
}
```

And in my view I had:

```
@Html.TextBox("Image", string.Empty, new { type = "file" })
```